# Riemann sums lower and upper sums

Tags: calculus, riemann-sum

$x^2+x+1$ between $x=-1$ and $x=3$ two subintervals
$x_0=-1,x_1=2,x_2=3$ find lower and upper Riemann sums.

workings
lower bound
$(b-a)/n=2$, $2f(0)+2f(1)=2(1)+2(7)=16$ 
teacher solution $37/4$ 
not sure how this solution was derived

Comment: If partition is $-1,2,3$ then all intervals not same size, so can't use the $(b-a)/n$ formula.

Comment: okay so do i apply difference in x0-x1=3 byf(0) +f(1)

Comment: "teacher solution" is 37/4 to which --- the lower sum or the upper? There should be really two separate answers, one for each of lower/upper Riemann sums.

Comment: solution provided was for lower bound I am just trying to workout what the process is

Comment: would love some workings towards solving problem.

Comment: Which source have you gotten upper and lower sums from?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the interval $[-1,2]$ the minimum of $f(x)=x^2+x+1$ occurs at its vertex, which has first coordinate $x=-1/2.$ This can be checked using the derivative $f'(x)=2x+1$ which set to zero gives $x=-1/2,$ but this in itself doesn't force it to be the minimum, one also has to compare the $f(x)$ values at the two endpoints $-1$ and $2.$ Then $f(-1)=1,\ f(-1/2)=3/4,\ f(2)=7.$ Now the length of the interval $[-1,2]$ is $3$ which is multiplied by the minimum just found, namely $3/4,$ to get the contribution to the Riemann sum from the left interval. So that is $9/4$ so far. The other interval is $[2,3]$ and since $f$ is increasing on that interval the min occurs when $x=2$ and is $f(2)=7.$ Since the interval $[2,3]$ has length $1$ this means the second interval just contributes $7$ to the Riemann sum, so that adding both gives $9/4+7=37/4.$

Comment: thanks i work through what you have suggested.

Comment: @Liz For the min of any simple function $f$ on a closed interval $[a,b]$ I was using the two step process (1) Find any points in the interior $(a,b )$ of the closed interval where $f'=0$ or $f'$ is undefined, (2) Calculate the value of $f$ at the points (if any) from step (1) AND at the endpoints $a,b.$ The smallest is then the min, and the largest is the max.

Answer (score 0):

Upper and lower riemann sums don't work with endpoints, but with the maximum and minimum value.

For the upper you value the function is the point of the subinterval when it is max, for the lower you value it in the point where is min.

It has nothing to do with left or right end points of each interval ;-)